# Залить файлы/папки на гуглдиск с помощью терминала (linux)

Tags: linux, консоль, google-drive

Нужно залить файлы/папки на гугл диск с помощью командной строки в линукс.
Например, у меня есть папки
**a/b1** и **a/b2**
**a** - папка, **b1** и **b2** - папки или файлы внутри папки a.
У меня установлена Gdrive утилиты https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
Но когда я с помощью нее делаю

```
gdrive upload a/b1
gdrive upload a/b2
```

она просто создает две папки а в моем гугл диске.
Примечание:
я не могу использовать просто

```
gdrive upload a
```

т.к. у меня нету места на диске, чтобы одновременно хранить файл/папку b1 и b2